# Numpy 2D array: I need to check if any of the first n-2 elements of an array are nan and make sure n-1 is not

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2 dimensional numpy array and I need to return only the inner arrays that have nan in the first n-2 elements and do not have nan for the n-1 element.

I am working with Numpy arrays in python

x = [[14, nan, 15, 0], [12, 23, 24, nan], [12, nan, 13, nan], [12, 12, 12, 12]]

and the result for x should be [[14, nan, 15, 0]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[14, np.nan, 15, 0], [12, 23, 24, np.nan], [12, np.nan, 13, np.nan]])

isnan = np.isnan(x)
answer = x[np.any(isnan[:,:-1],axis=1) & np.logical_not(isnan[:,-1])]
             
print(answer)
```

gives:

```
[[ 14.  nan  15.   0.]]
```

This works by making a boolean array of which rows satisfy the condition (here `[True False False]`), and then using advanced indexing.

The `np.logical_not(isnan[:,-1])` part could be written `~isnan[:,-1]` if preferred.

Note: I am understanding the "first n-2" in the question to mean elements 0 to n-2 (of which there are n-1 in total). If this is not correct, then the indices can be adjusted accordingly, e.g. `[:,:-2]` if you mean elements 0 to n-3 inclusive (n-2 elements).